# Filter by ipAddress for auditLogs/signIns doesn't seem to work

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use Microsoft Graph to filter by `ipAddress`, but I am still getting results with other IP addresses.

The url I'm using is:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=startswith(ipAddress,'185.255.31.125')&$top=1000
```

If someone is able to spot an error in my filter syntax or can post a working ipAddress filter it would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `startswith` instead of `eq` for your filter? If you're looking for strict filtering with equals condition, you can try something like `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=ipAddress eq '185.255.31.125'&$top=1000`  It works as expected for me.

Comment: @RohitSaigal There no reason why I'm not using eq. I tried it before with out the single quote and it failed. I just tried what you sent and it worked. So thank you!

Comment: ok that sounds good, I'll add it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for strict filtering, try equals `eq` instead of `startswith`. It works as expected.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=ipAddress eq '185.255.31.125'&$top=1000`